# MATLAB simple slider on a figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a matrix to be plotted one column at a time. Is it possible to add a slider to a MATLAB figure (without heavy GUI programming) so that by moving the slider, different columns are shown in the current axis?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it's not gonna be a one-liner trivial. You need to add a slider and write a callback.

Do you have in mind Mathematica?

Comment: Yes, maybe something like that. I have done it via creating an interface using GLIDE. But it seems that there are commands (uicontrol) to place controls on a figure. I am wondering what is the minimal piece of code which seamlessly integrates with an already existing Matlab script. I don't mind writing a callback, but I don't want to carry all the data around in those objects the get passed from callback to callback. Is it possible for the callback to read the data from the workspace?

Comment: You can plot all bars at once and set them to invisible (except the first one), then the slider will simply set the visible to the one of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a code for a slider to plot corresponding column:

```
m = ones(5,1)*(1:5);
slmin = 1;
slmax = size(m,2);
plot(m(:,1))
hsl = uicontrol('Style','slider','Min',slmin,'Max',slmax,...
                'SliderStep',[1 1]./(slmax-slmin),'Value',1,...
                'Position',[20 20 200 20]);
set(hsl,'Callback',@(hObject,eventdata) plot(m(:,round(get(hObject,'Value')))) )
```

---

**EDIT**:

For better performance you can just update the `YData` values:

```
set(hsl,'Callback',@(hObject,eventdata) ...
    set(hline,'YData',m(:,round(get(hObject,'Value')))) )
```

To fix y axes limit, just set them manually with `ylim([0 6])` after first `plot` call.

Comment: This example is a bit misleading. It re-plots every time which is not optimal from many points of view, but one thing which is immediate are the changing `xlims`. It looks like the slider changes the yaxis rather than the line.

Comment: You are right. Performance wise it's faster to reset the `YData` for the line object. Although it's possible that the new data can be out of current limits.

Comment: That's why I would recommend to plot everything, customize the axis, hide some data and link the slider to hide/show the relevant "columns".

Comment: I agree, callback function can be implemented differently, depending on task.

Comment: Thanks, yuk. Both seem to work, and they are both fast enough on my computer. Setting YData automatically adjusts the axis limits in my version of MATLAB.

Comment: @Oleg, plotting and hiding seems an interesting idea, and I might try it. For my case, it might be too much work as there are supposed to be multiple things plotted on the same axis, at each slider step.

Comment: Now if it was possible to make the plots change in real time while dragging the slider .... I remember being able to do so by attaching a listener to 'PostSet ' callback of the slider, but the details seem to elude me.

Comment: OK. I have also figure out the change-as-dragged issue. One uses  addlistener(hsl,'Value','PostSet', @sliderDragged); and in sliderDragged, one can access the value of the slider by using eventdata.newValue.

Answer (score 5):

The code to create a slider is reasonable minimal:

```
uicontrol('Style', 'slider', 'Callback', @sliderCallback);

function sliderCallback(hObject, evt)
    fprintf('Slider value is: %d\n', get(hObject, 'Value') );
end
```

You will want to look at properties such as `Position`, to set the position on the figure, and `Max` and `Min` to set the possible range of values.  Also note that if you do this inside a function, your `sliderCallback` can be a nested function which will probably make it easier to redraw your display.  If you run this in a script, `sliderCallback` will have to be in a separate file.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using a nested function (within a function) for the callback, since then I can use the variables in the workspace of the function directly.