# MATLAB adding slider on a figure

Tags: matlab

I have a 576x576x150 matrix. Each 576x576 set represents an image. When I want to plot one frame I do it by using the plot command:

```
figure(1);
imshow(B(:,:,45),[]) % plots frame 45
title('45') % tells frame number
```

However I would like to add a slider to the plot, so I can move from 1-150 frame within the figure.I've seen examples of people using uicontrol but I don't know how to code it. In addition to that, I would like to have a title on top of the figure telling me the frame number.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975758/matlab-simple-slider-on-a-figure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I do it. I like to keep a single function that does the plotting so you don't recycle commands elsewhere. You could replace the first two lines by `function test(B)` to use you own `B` matrix. This code is pretty easy to extend. You will also want to play with the layout to suit your purpose.

```
function test
B=rand(576,576,150);

fig=figure(100);
set(fig,'Name','Image','Toolbar','figure',...
    'NumberTitle','off')
% Create an axes to plot in
axes('Position',[.15 .05 .7 .9]);
% sliders for epsilon and lambda
slider1_handle=uicontrol(fig,'Style','slider','Max',150,'Min',1,...
    'Value',2,'SliderStep',[1/(150-1) 10/(150-1)],...
    'Units','normalized','Position',[.02 .02 .14 .05]);
uicontrol(fig,'Style','text','Units','normalized','Position',[.02 .07 .14 .04],...
    'String','Choose frame');
% Set up callbacks
vars=struct('slider1_handle',slider1_handle,'B',B);
set(slider1_handle,'Callback',{@slider1_callback,vars});
plotterfcn(vars)
% End of main file

% Callback subfunctions to support UI actions
function slider1_callback(~,~,vars)
    % Run slider1 which controls value of epsilon
    plotterfcn(vars)

function plotterfcn(vars)
    % Plots the image
    imshow(vars.B(:,:,get(vars.slider1_handle,'Value')));
    title(num2str(get(vars.slider1_handle,'Value')));
```

Comment: I replaced the second line with load('frames.mat'), which contains a B(576,576,150) matrix but it is not working :S

Comment: NO error but the all the frames are white!!! maybe is a windowing issue. before I was using: `a=min(min(min(B,[],1)));`
`b=max(max(max(B,[],1)));` and then `imshow(B(:,:,frame),[a b])` but I don't know how to add that to your code (if that is the issue).

Comment: **Confirmed.** It a windowing problem. When I modified the second to last line to `imshow(vars.B(:,:,get(vars.slider1_handle,'Value')),[]);` it works, but I still to add _min_ = a and _max_ = a e.g. `imshow(vars.B(:,:,get(vars.slider1_handle,'Value')),[a b]);` to have the same windowing across all images.

Comment: Ah OK, I am not familiar with `imshow`. Glad you worked it out.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use `uicontrol()` to enable sliding/scrolling.

The following code is for scrolling (created by [Evan Brooks](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5253-scrolling-figure-demo), you can modify it to sliding):

```
function scrollfigdemo

% create new figure window
f = figure;
set(f,'doublebuffer', 'on', 'resize', 'off')

% set columns of plots
cols = 2;

% create 5 data sets to plot
x=0:1e-2:2*pi;
y{1}=sin(x);
y{2}=cos(x);
y{3}=tan(x);
y{4}=x.^2;
y{5}=x.^3;

% determine required rows of plots
rows = ceil(length(y)/cols);

% increase figure width for additional axes
fpos = get(gcf, 'position');
scrnsz = get(0, 'screensize');
fwidth = min([fpos(3)*cols, scrnsz(3)-20]);
fheight = fwidth/cols*.75; % maintain aspect ratio
set(gcf, 'position', [10 fpos(2) fwidth fheight])

% setup all axes
buf = .15/cols; % buffer between axes & between left edge of figure and axes
awidth = (1-buf*cols-.08/cols)/cols; % width of all axes
aidx = 1;
rowidx = 0;
while aidx <= length(y)
    for i = 0:cols-1
        if aidx+i <= length(y)
            start = buf + buf*i + awidth*i;
            apos{aidx+i} = [start 1-rowidx-.92 awidth .85];
            a{aidx+i} = axes('position', apos{aidx+i});
        end
    end
    rowidx = rowidx + 1; % increment row
    aidx = aidx + cols;  % increment index of axes
end

% make plots
axes(a{1}), plot(x,y{1}), title('sine'), xlabel('x'), ylabel('sin(x)')
axes(a{2}), plot(x,y{2}), title('cosine'), xlabel('x'), ylabel('cos(x)')
axes(a{3}), plot(x,y{3}), title('tangent'), xlabel('x'), ylabel('tan(x)')
axes(a{4}), plot(x,y{4}), title('x^2'), xlabel('x'), ylabel('x^2')
axes(a{5}), plot(x,y{5}), title('x^3'), xlabel('x'), ylabel('x^3')

% determine the position of the scrollbar & its limits
swidth = max([.03/cols, 16/scrnsz(3)]);
ypos = [1-swidth 0 swidth 1];
ymax = 0;
ymin = -1*(rows-1);

% build the callback that will be executed on scrolling
clbk = '';
for i = 1:length(a)
    line = ['set(',num2str(a{i},'%.13f'),',''position'',[', ...
            num2str(apos{i}(1)),' ',num2str(apos{i}(2)),'-get(gcbo,''value'') ', num2str(apos{i}(3)), ...
            ' ', num2str(apos{i}(4)),'])'];
    if i ~= length(a)
        line = [line,','];
    end
    clbk = [clbk,line];
end

% create the slider
uicontrol('style','slider', ...
    'units','normalized','position',ypos, ...
    'callback',clbk,'min',ymin,'max',ymax,'value',0);
```